# ansible uri module is throwin a "password not registered error"

Tags: ansible, uri

while I am trying to tell Ansible to use this curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://34.107.103.175:3009/rest/v1.0/auth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "sysadmin",
    "password": "8529834022607504819"
}'
```

This will return a -DD-AUTH-TOKEN in the header but I am failing to tell the ReST endpoint the json Body

```json
{
    "username": "sysadmin",
    "password": "{{DD-Old_Password}}"
}
```

My ansible approach

```
vars:
    DDVE_public_IP: 34.107.103.175
    destination_port: 3009
    Instance_id: 8529834022607504819
    S3_bucket_name: bucket_for_ddve_6

  tasks:
    - name: login access token
      uri:
        validate_certs: false
        url: https://{{ DDVE_public_IP }}:{{ destination_port }}/{{ resource_path }}
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        body: 
          username: sysadmin
          password: 8529834022607504819
        body_format: json
        return_content: true
      register: rest_post
      vars:
        resource_path: rest/v1.0/auth
```

is failing with

```yaml
TASK [login access token] *********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"access_control_allow_credentials": "true", "access_control_expose_headers": "AUTHORIZATION, X-DD-AUTH-TOKEN, X-DD-JSON-RESPONSE-WITH-ROOT, X-DD-PEER-USERNAME", "cache_control": "no-cache", "changed": false, "content": "{\"details\": \"**** Value of \\\"password\\\" is empty.\", \"code\": 5437}", "content_length": "65", "content_type": "application/json", "elapsed": 0, "json": {"code": 5437, "details": "**** Value of \"password\" is empty."}, "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", "redirected": false, "server": "Data Domain OS", "status": 400, "url": "https://34.107.103.175:3009/rest/v1.0/auth", "x_dd_auth_token": "", "x_dd_uuid": "857cd83f41d01670:68e24c1d986399ff"}
```

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Why does it show this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the upstream service is failing due to a type error. YAML coerces `[0-9]+` into a formal `int` scalar; so if your password is entirely digits but should be transmitted as a `str`, you'll need to explicitly quote it:

```yaml
        body: 
          username: sysadmin
          password: '8529834022607504819'
```

if you would prefer to use the `var`, you'll need to similarly "cast" it because the var is also an `int` for the same YAML coercion reason:

```yaml
        body: 
          username: sysadmin
          password: "{{ Instance_id | string }}"
```

*(be aware that the `"` in that example is merely protecting the jinja2 mustaches, and doesn't have anything to do with the type of the inner variable)*

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. Glad to have you figuring out my inability

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Please consider marking the answer as accepted in order to let others know it worked for you